# Azure Mobile Service LoginAsync with Facebook Token is Unauthorized

Tags: facebook, azure, facebook-c#-sdk, azure-mobile-services

I'm following the post at http://ntotten.com/2013/03/14/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-with-the-facebook-sdk-for-windows-phone/ and I can successfully get a Facebook access token. However when I submit the access token as a `JObject` to the `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(provider, token)` method I get an `IvalidOperationException (Unauthorized)`. The Code, Request and Response (from the exception) are below...

### Code

```
private async Task Authenticate()
{
    while (user == null)
    {
        try
        {
            fbSession = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("email,publish_stream,friends_about_me");
            var client = new FacebookClient(fbSession.AccessToken);
            var token = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                access_token = fbSession.AccessToken
            });
            user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, token); // this line causes the exception
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### Request

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://[MY-DOMAIN].azure-mobile.net/login/facebook', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: f13ec5fb-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-f249415499de
  X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: jUjMFbasVpKwbktxTWcBShXXXXXXXXXX
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/1.0
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.10.0.12359; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20402.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.10.0.12359; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20402.0)
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 223
}}
```

### Response

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Service"
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=e1254f762d2198b2b306557ef6b226a2d9f70aac5e3cc654c3381bXXXXXXXXXX;Path=/;Domain=[MY-DOMAIN].azure-mobile.net
  Date: Sun, 20 Apr 2014 17:37:00 GMT
  Content-Length: 0
}}
```

If I remove the Facebook client access and leverage the `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(provider)` method instead, the Facebook authentication is successful but I want to have access to the Client SDK on the phone so I'm sure I've missed something. Unfortunately all my debugging and searching has left me stumped.

Comment: Is the `FacebookSessionClient` object created with the same application id as you have configured in your service?

Comment: Just double checked... yes, the Identity in the management portal is the same as the `FacebookSessionClient` constructor. Thanks for helping me with this..

Comment: I've been troubleshooting this issue all night with Microsoft Account as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `WWW-Authenticate` header in the response I'm assuming you're using the .NET backend for the mobile service. Login with the token from access providers (Facebook / Microsoft) is still not supported in the .NET backend. If you use a mobile service with the node.js backend, then you should be able to use that code on the client-side to login to the mobile service.

Support for client-side login for those providers should come in the near future for the mobile services .NET backend.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Carlos. I am using the .NET backend for this project. I've used the node.js backend in another project and has access to the getIdentities function for server side access to the token... is this token information passed to the TableController somewhere?

Comment: I worked out the answer to my follow up and posted as a full answer in case others are looking for this info.

Comment: Update: the .NET backend now supports authentication with token from login providers. Check the post at http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/logging-in-with-google-microsoft-and-facebook-sdks-to-azure-mobile-services/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue I added a User table to my DB, including a column called `FacebookToken`. I can then capture the Facebook access token from the Claim when a new user is being added to the table (or from any other operation on the `Controller`).

My `PostUser` method now looks like the following;

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUser(User item)
{
    //get current user and facebook token...
    var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
    Claim fbClaim = currentUser.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:microsoft:credentials");
    JToken accessToken = JToken.Parse(fbClaim.Value);

    //set the facebook token on the User object...
    item.FacebookToken = accessToken["accessToken"].Value<string>();

    //insert the user record...
    User current = await InsertAsync(item);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```