# Mobile Service Login from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to authenticate a user with Azure Mobile Services from within a ASP.NET Web Form (.aspx.cs).

I have provisioned my Mobile Service to authenticate with Facebook using the steps described here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/.

This tutorial, however, describes authenticating in a XAML app where popups can appear, but I need to Log the user in within a postback of the web form, where showing a popup is impossible.

According to the docs I can do this by using the LoginAsync() function, like this":

```
MobileServiceClient client = MyAppsMobileClient.getClient(); //this handles setting the app ID and url
MobileServiceUser user = client.LoginAsync("facebook","");
```

Now, my problem is the second argument of this function. According to the docs, this is of type JObject, and apparently it is a JSON object I obtain from facebook when I first log in. Now, I can make a simple Login form for the user to enter his facebook ID and password, but I still don't know how to obtain the JObject I need to log in to Mobile Services. Do I need to delve into the Facebook APIs? Is this done using Ajax? Any examples, guides or tutorials on this would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jObject from the data received from Facebook like this:

```
 var token = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            access_token = "YOUR TOKEN HERE"
   });
```

This sample was taken from this SO thread:

[Azure Mobile Service LoginAsync with Facebook Token is Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185985/azure-mobile-service-loginasync-with-facebook-token-is-unauthorized)

And here you can read how to obtain an access token from Facebook using JavaScript:

[Obtaining an Access Token](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/#4)